# Get a list of Desktop names in XenDesktop

Tags: powershell, citrix, xendesktop

I've done this but its not giving me what I want.

```
Get-BrokerDesktop -MaxRecordCount 1000 | select "DesktopGroupName" | Export-Csv c:\dektop_list
```

I'm only looking to get Delivery Groups that publish desktops. If its a published app delivery group I dont want it included in the list.

Thanks in advance.

```
   $DG = Get-BrokerDesktopGroup
   foreach($item in $DG)
   {
      if (DeliveryType = "DesktopsOnly")
        {
            Add-Content C:\dektop_list.csv
        }
        else
        {
            Add-Content c:\application_delivery.csv
        }
        }
```

I get an error on this that says"DeliveryType : The term 'DeliveryType' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: $DG = Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -MaxRecordCount 10000 | Where-Object {$_.DeliveryType -like "Desktopsandapps" -and "DesktopsOnly"} | Select-Object "PublishedName" this is where I got to. But it doesnt find both Desktopsandapps and DesktopsOnly

Comment: Here is the final command

$DG = Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -MaxRecordCount 10000 | Where-Object {$_.DeliveryType -like "DesktopsOnly" -or $_.DeliveryType -like "DesktopsAndApps" } | Select-Object "PublishedName"

Comment: so you are ok? your command is working?, if so update the answer and accept it...

Answer (score 1):

This command will list Published Desktops:

`Get-BrokerEntitlementPolicyRule -Property Name, PublishedName`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final command $DG = Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -MaxRecordCount 10000 | Where-Object {$*.DeliveryType -like "DesktopsOnly" -or $*.DeliveryType -like "DesktopsAndApps" } | Select-Object "PublishedName"

Answer (score 0):

I've scouted around for the command to list the actual name used for the desktop as published in the web portal. Albeit such commands such as:

```
Get-BrokerDesktopGroup | ? {$_.DeliveryType -match "Desktops"  } | Select -Property Name, PublishedName
```

or

```
Get-BrokerDesktop | select DesktopGroupName, AssociatedUserNames | ft -AutoSize
```

can be used to list the various object names assigned to the delivery group, I have not found anything that shows the published name shown in the storefront web portal.

Nevertheless, hopefully the above may suffice for some of you.

Enjoy,

Porky